# Can this chilli plant be identified from leaf shape and size? It has started to bud, but no flowers or fruit yet

Tags: identification, chili

[image]This chilli plant was grown from a seed given to me by a friend, can it be positively identified before it bares fruit? Other photo is of one of its flowers, the buds take a long time to actually flower.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a pepper plant to me. Dozens of them look like that.

Comment: Are the lower leaves from the same plant? You might get a species ID, but to ID the breed would be guesswork in most circumstances, especially at this point. What did you friend tell you about the seed?

Comment: Lower leaves are from a habanero, I think it is either ghost chilli or scorpion chilli. Pretty sure it is one of the hotter ones.